# How to enable "system assigned" identity and update the key vault to add new access policy azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

How to enable "system assigned" identity and also update the key vault to add new access policy using azure cli...

Tried below command but it complaints that it cannot find RG for some reason or i'm missing something.
az webapp identity assign --name   --resource-group

[image: A]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tried below command but it complaints that it cannot find RG for some reason or i'm missing something.

The command you used is correct, make sure you input the resource group name correctly, also make sure you run the command under a correct subscription via `az account show`, if not, use [`az account set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-set) to set it.

```
az account set --subscription '<subscription-id>'
az webapp identity assign --name '<webapp-name>' --resource-group '<group-name>'
```

[image]

Then if you want to add the system-assigned identity to the access policies of the keyvault, use [`az keyvault set-policy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-set-policy). (wait for several minutes after `az webapp identity assign`, the service principal related to the identity need to be created in Azure AD)

Sample(the `<object-id>` is the `principalId` returned by `az webapp identity assign`):

```
az keyvault set-policy --name '<keyvault-name>' --resource-group '<group-name>' --object-id '<object-id>' --secret-permissions get list delete
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the solution Joy. When i ran identity assign command i'm getting {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/webapp' under resource group 'resource-group-name' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"}}

Comment: Btw, i was able to run the command successfully for the appservice itself but not for the deployment slot and i want to enable the identity for the deployment slot as part of my CICD pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. was able to successfully configure for the deployment slot as well.. i was missing --slot flag.